# VBA custom procedure/function in Worksheet called outside its module

Tags: function, vba, reference, worksheet

I've been playing with this problem for some time, and havent figured out how to do it.
**I have the same function in every worksheet** (and those sheets are named like this Name="One", CodeName="SheetOne" ...):

```
const someVar as Boolean = True

Public Function myFunction() as Boolean
myFunction = someVar
End Function
```

Now I want it to be called from outside like this - In ThisWorkbook there is procedure  "doThis()" and function "TestThis():

```
Sub doThis()
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
   If testThis(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)) = True then
      Debug.print "Success!"
   End If
Next i

Function testThis(x As Worksheet)
If x.myFunction = True Then
   testThis = True
Else
   testThis = False
End If
```

Now I know that at this line "**If x.myFunction = True**" it throws error "Method or data member not found", because i cant call that function with this reference, so I've tried it with VBComponent:

```
Sub doThis()
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
   If testThis(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(i).CodeName)) _
   = True then
      Debug.print "Success!"
   End If
Next i

Function testThis(x As VBComponent)
If x.myFunction = True Then
   testThis = True
Else
   testThis = False
End If
```

But again, it throws an "Object does not support this property or method" error. Any ideas, How can I call that function from a variable, that has stored reference of any kind to that Worksheet? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling the code, Excel checks to see if "WorkSheet" object type has a `myFunction` method - it is looking at the generic built-in Worksheet object, and this doesn't include your "add on" function (and neither does the "VBComponent" type), so it throws an error.

If you change your parameter type to Object (a more generic type) then it will compile...

```
Function testThis(x As Object)
    testThis = x.myFunction()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Changed "x" to Object type, it compiles fine, but crashes again on attempt to call "x.myFunction" (Runtime error 438 - object doesnt support this property or method). Even Variant seems to not solve this.

Comment: Do all your sheet have `myFunction` defined?  Maybe you could update your question with your exact current code.

Comment: All Worksheets in that Workbook has the exact same function. And I should point out that unfortunately I cant use some Interface there. If needed, I can explain why (edit main qustion).

Comment: Well, it works for me...  I don't know what you mean by "I can't use some interface there"

Comment: I've tried to create a class, for example "IMyInterface", that has one function, then implement it in every worksheet with `implements IMyInterface`. Then you have to write implementation of that function everywhere and then, instead of `testThis(x As Object)`, you can use `testThis(x As IMyInterface)` ... this just works fine. But it fails if you create new Sheets, because these sheets wont have that implementation yet. But nevermind, thanks for your interest, I should do this in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I thought I may as well share my discoveries.
Also, I suspect there is a better way to evaluate the exact same function in every sheet but, for anyone searching, here is a solution to do exactly what you asked for in the title of the post.

In your `ThisWorkbook` include

```
Const myFunction = "myFunctuion"
Public ws as Worksheet

For each ws in Me.Sheets
    If testThis(ws) then Debug.print "Success!"
next ws

Function testThis(x as Worksheet)
    testThis = callByName x, x.CodeName & "." & myFunction
End Function
```